# Is there a way to display only the filtered results?

Tags: java, android, cs50

I am attempting cs50 Android track

("https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/tracks/mobile/android/pokedex/")

( full source at source code at "https://cdn.cs50.net/2019/fall/tracks/android/pokedex/pokedex.zip"), and i am trying to display only the filtered pokemon, and my search function is not working

How do i make the perfomFIltering update whenever a word is typed, and diplay only that word(pokemon)

Here is my code with the changes

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.pokedex.Pokemon;
import com.example.pokedex.PokemonActivity;
import com.example.pokedex.R;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class PokedexAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PokedexAdapter.PokedexViewHolder> implements Filterable {
    private List<Pokemon> pokemon = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Pokemon> filteredPokemon = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Pokemon> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;

    public static class PokedexViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public LinearLayout containerView;
        public TextView textView;

        PokedexViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            containerView = view.findViewById(R.id.pokedex_row);
            textView = view.findViewById(R.id.pokedex_row_text_view);

            containerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Pokemon current = (Pokemon) containerView.getTag();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), PokemonActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("url", current.getUrl());

                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }



    PokedexAdapter(Context context) {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        loadPokemon();
    }

    public void loadPokemon() {
        String url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray results = response.getJSONArray("results");
                    for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name = result.getString("name");
                        pokemon.add(new Pokemon(
                                name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1),
                                result.getString("url")
                        ));
                    }

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("cs50", "Json error", e);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("cs50", "Pokemon list error", error);
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PokedexViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.pokedex_row, parent, false);

        return new PokedexViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PokedexViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Pokemon current = filtered.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(current.getName());
        holder.containerView.setTag(current);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return filtered.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new PokemonFilter();
    }
    private class PokemonFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint.length() == 0)
            {
                results.values = pokemon;
                results.count = pokemon.size();
            }
            else
            {
                for (Pokemon current : pokemon)
                {
                    if (current.getName().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                    {
                        filteredPokemon.add(current);
                    }
                }
                results.values = filteredPokemon; // you need to create this variable!
                results.count = filteredPokemon.size();
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filtered = (List<Pokemon>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

mostly with the string comparison, i think the problem is there

Answer (score 0):

do you try the functions of Java 8 Stream and Filter:

```
String search = "pikachu";
this.pokemon
.stream()
.filter(p ->  p.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(search ))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace `startWith()` with `contains()` so you can filter any intermediate text

Also add `.trim()` to avoid leading/trailing spaces.

So change the below condition

```
if (current.getName().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
```

With

```
if (current.getName().toUpperCase().contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase().trim()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised where the error was, I was not updating the reults for every letter typed in

```
                for (Pokemon name : pokemon) {
                    if (name.getName().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                        filteredPokemon.add(name);
                        results.values = filteredPokemon; // you need to create this variable!
                        results.count = filteredPokemon.size();
                    }
                }
```

That way for every letter in search, it only brings the results that start with it

Thank you for your help though